# How to remove duplicate html tags from a string - php / regex

Tags: php, regex

I have some html files created by some bad online html editor. The user is selecting any text and press the italic button then the text will be inserted into `<em></em>` tags.

By using this functions - sometimes the user put some text italic then remove it and then he change back to italic again.

In many cases i receive bad HTML code with duplicate tags like below:

Example #1:

```html
Adding insult to injury, <em><em>Jennifer <a href="somelink">Aniston</a></em> had literally <a href="somelink2">zero clue</a> what was coming.</em>
```

Example #2:

```html
Adding insult to injury, <em><em>Jennifer Aniston</em> had literally <a href="somelink2">zero clue</a> what was coming.</em>
```

The question is how to remove the duplicate tags - `<em>`-tags inside another `<em>`tags are not necessary and should be removed.

i wrote a code, but its not working very well - the beautiful solution would be with reg exp - i was try some regex but was not working, so i moved to another way:

```php
function repairDoubleTags($line = '', $rtag = 'em') {
    if(empty($line)) return false;

    if(!preg_match("#<".$rtag.">#", $line)) 
        return $line;

    $tmp = explode(" ", $line);
    //print_r($tmp);

    $lastposition = -1;
    $remove_next = 0;

    foreach($tmp as $nr => $word) {     
        //echo $word."\r\n";

        if(empty($word)) {
            unset($tmp[$nr]);
            continue;
        }

        if(preg_match("#<".$rtag.">#", $word)) {
            if($lastposition == -1) {
                $lastposition = $nr;
                //echo "----------------- ".$rtag." FOUND\r\n";
            }else {
                $tmp[$nr] = trim(preg_replace("#<".$rtag.">#", "", $tmp[$nr]));
                $remove_next = 1;
                $lastposition = -1;
                //echo "----------------- DOUBLE ".$rtag." FOUND AND REMOVED\r\n";
            }
        }

        if(preg_match("#</".$rtag.">#", $word)) {
            if($remove_next == 1) {
                $tmp[$nr] = trim(preg_replace("#</".$rtag.">#", "", $tmp[$nr]));
                $remove_next = 0;
                //echo "----------------- DOUBLE END ".$rtag." FOUND AND REMOVED\r\n";
            }else {
                $lastposition = -1;
            }
        }

        if(empty($tmp[$nr]))
            unset($tmp[$nr]);

    }

    //print_r($tmp);
    $line = join(' ', $tmp);
    //print_r($line);
    //exit;

    return $line;
}
```

But this code is not working if html code has more than one `<em>` - as example not working when:

```html
Adding insult to injury, <em><em>Jennifer Aniston</em> had literally <a href="somelink2">zero clue</a> what <em>was coming</em>.</em>
```

Any `regex` expert for a fast nice solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the wrong tool for the job. FYI: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.tidy.php

Comment: Hi perhaps run it through an HTML minifier if you'd like to eliminate the redundancy? It might be difficult to handle all the possible cases with a regex.

Comment: Regex is probably overkill as sometimes double tags are permissible HTML (e.g. `<div><div>`. So either look for specific issues to fix (e.g. replace `<em><em>` with `<em>` or consider using an HTML tidying tool such as PHP Tidy or maybe an API such as: http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/tidylib_api_next/

Comment: @ficuscr wow, thanks, thats exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @lufc i tried, but its not always that tags are stick together. - there are lot of variations - its not that easy to catch every situation

Comment: i tried php_tidy. its repairing HTML code but not clean redundancy. redundancy stays.

Comment: @jspcal yes the point is to eliminate redundancy

Comment: You make a confusion between html code (that separates the data as XML does) and rendering. em means "emphasis", but it doesn't mean "put that in italic". Even if by default browsers show em enclosed text in italic, nothing forbids a css rule to puts for instance the first level in italic and the second level in bold. In other words: do not think that html tags are useful in any way for presentation. They are only here to structure the data and to define a hierarchy.

Comment: Other thing, to edit an html document, you **must** use DOMDocument that provides an html parser. Regex and other direct string approaches are a bad way to edit a language as complicated as html (or any other programming language).

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit complicated to guess what might be other invalid `<em>` that we might be having here, yet if you wish to explore regular expression option, we can likely start with an expression similar to:

```
(?=<em><em>)(<em>)(.*?)(<\/em>)
```

and make a replacement with `$2`. This would be just an example, and the expression is undoubtedly prone to failure.

> If we might have other invalid tags, other than `em`, we would simply loop through the expression and make the replacements.

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?=<em><em>)(<em>)(.*?)(<\/em>)/m';
$str = 'Adding insult to injury, <em><em>Jennifer <a href="somelink">Aniston</a></em> had literally <a href="somelink2">zero clue</a> what was coming.</em>

Adding insult to injury, <em><em>Jennifer Aniston</em> had literally <a href="somelink2">zero clue</a> what was coming.</em>
Adding insult to injury, <em><em>Jennifer Aniston</em> had literally <a href="somelink2">zero clue</a> what was coming.</em>

';
$subst = '$2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

[Please see the demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/8iIxNh/1/)

#### Output

```
Adding insult to injury, <em>Jennifer <a href="somelink">Aniston</a> had literally <a href="somelink2">zero clue</a> what was coming.</em>

Adding insult to injury, <em>Jennifer Aniston had literally <a href="somelink2">zero clue</a> what was coming.</em>
Adding insult to injury, <em>Jennifer Aniston had literally <a href="somelink2">zero clue</a> what was coming.</em>
```

Comment: good approach, unfortunately not exactly - the first and the last em should stay. (in a sentence). the last </em> isnt always on the end of the sentence. 
i can try to split the sentences by .(dot)

Comment: very nice. thank you. just one more thing. to use this regex i need to identify first if i have redundancy <em> in <em>, if i do not have redundancy it will eliminate the wanted <em>s